# EF core code first migrations automatically prefixing Tables with db_owner

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am currently using EF Core 2.1 code first migrations to create my SQL server schema. When I use the following command to create/update my tables in SQL server"

```
dotnet ef database update
```

it prefixes my tables with "db_owner". For example "db_owner.drivers".

Is there a way to set the db prefix name from my ef configuration file in code? Or is this something that is actually configured in SQL server itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `ToTable` in your dbContext to set scheme name, if you do not specify that, EF core will use `dbo` by convention.

```
 public class MyDbContext
 {
   private string schemaName = "MyPrefix";
   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().ToTable("MyTable", schemaName );
    }
 }
```

If you would like to set schemaName in configuration file(appsettings.json):

```
{
  "schemaName": "MyPrefix",
}
```

You could get configuration in dbContext file using DI.

```
public class MyDbContext
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;     
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, IConfiguration configuration)
        : base(options)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    ...// DbSet<>

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().ToTable("MyTable", _configuration["schemaName"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes actually when I do it on localhost it uses dbo by default and dbowner on my vm server by default. I will give this a try first thing tomorrow and get back to you

Comment: That was extremely easy and surprisingly I could not find this in the EF documentation. Thanks!